# How to add custom llvm to VS2019

Tags: llvm, visual-studio-2019

I have downloaded an installed LLVM 10 on Win 10 machine, which already had VS2019-Enterprise.

Created the Directory.build.props file as:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LLVMInstallDir>full_path_to_my_llvm</LLVMInstallDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Ran MSBuild while on the directory that contains *.sln* and *.vxproj* files.

Still cannot get see llvm under ConfigurationProperties->General->PlatformToolset.

How does one add LLVM to VS2019?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue myself, so I'll post the solution since I came across this question while searching for an answer.

[Clang/LLVM support in Visual Studio projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/clang-support-msbuild?view=vs-2019)

> For best IDE support in Visual Studio, we recommend using the latest Clang compiler tools for Windows. If you don't already have those, you can install them by opening the Visual Studio Installer and choosing C++ Clang tools for Windows under Desktop development with C++ optional components. **If you prefer to use an existing Clang installation on your machine, choose the "C++ Clang-cl for v142 build tools." optional component.**

[C++ Clang-cl for v142 build tools (MSDN's image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iImBK.png)

All you have to do is install the 2nd component as shown. After you install that component, and load up Visual Studio again, you'll be able to select "LLVM (clang-cl)" from the Platform Toolset option.

That's all there was to it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Clang Power Tools extension to add any custom LLVM versions, starting with LLVM 4, directly from Visual Studio. (Disclaimer: I am the author of this extension.)

Go to CPT Settings -> select the LLVM Tab -> select the version you want to install by clicking the install button. No configuration is needed. Here is an [article about this feature](https://clangpowertools.com/blog/setting-up-llvm.html).

You can install multiple versions and decide later what version is better for you.

Comment: I'm undeleting this because it seems like a relevant and helpful answer. The major problem I suspect that other moderators had with it is the lack of a disclaimer of your affiliation. (I had really dig to figure out that you were the author. That should have been stated clearly, up front.) Before posting any more answers, please carefully review [our policies regarding affiliated projects](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), in order to ensure that you are not labeled as a spammer. Also worth a read: [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085)